# Creating a dictionary by using a C structure as an input in Python 2.3

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a structure in a file like this -

```
{ ATTR_u,
  READ_WRITE | ATR_DFLAG_SELEQ | ATR_DFLAG_SCGALT,
  ATR_TYPE_ARST,
  NULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,
  verify_value_user_list
 }
```

i would now like to make a dictionary out of it like this

```
my_dict = {'ATTR_u':[READ_WRITE | ATR_DFLAG_SELEQ | ATR_DFLAG_SCGALT,ATR_TYPE_ARST,NULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,verify_value_user_list]}
```

Could someone explain how to create the this dictionary? The only idea I have is to read the file and create a dictionary, a name value pair but can this be done?

Comment: Are the items in the list supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_text = """{ ATTR_u,
  READ_WRITE | ATR_DFLAG_SELEQ | ATR_DFLAG_SCGALT,
  ATR_TYPE_ARST,
  NULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,
  verify_value_user_list
 }"""

my_text = my_text.strip("{}")
my_list = [item.strip() for item in my_text.split(",")]
my_dict = {my_list[0]:my_list[1:]}
```

although its not entirely clear from your question what you are looking for ... I think this is it

Comment: actyally it wouldnt be that simple coz the structure is in a file,so the file has to be read line by line and then stored in a list (probably)! so in that case it would be something like if re.search(r'\{',word) and then search for the ending brace,once that is done we will start construction of the dictionary. where Key will be ATTR_u and rest the value so by the key we can replace the value.

Comment: `my_text = open("some_file.txt").read()` .... Im not sure what you mean by the rest of that comment ... is your input not like you stated in your question?

Comment: What i meant was this is a part of the program which will be handled in function and i'm not passing the entire file as a parameter to the function but storing all the lines in a list and then passing the list as an argument to the function.

Comment: ^ then you are passing an entire file as a parameter(your just passing it as a list of lines, which will be harder to parse than if it was just a block of text) ... anyway I still dont understand how this does not answer your question ...

Comment: Nope i was thinking aloud to the situation ,In fact this answers the question to a great extent.

Comment: what if i want the first structure member ATTR_u to be the key as well as a value in the value field?